# Convert code with using statements to fully-qualified names

Tags: c#, mono, xbuild

How do I convert a file originally written with `using` directives to be completely fully qualified names?

E.g. go from

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.XPath;

namespace ChatterBotAPI
{
    public interface ChatterBotSession
    {
        ChatterBotThought Think(ChatterBotThought thought);
        string Think(string text);
    }

    internal class PandorabotsSession : ChatterBotSession
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> vars;

        public PandorabotsSession(string botid)
        {
            vars = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            vars["botid"] = botid;
            vars["custid"] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public ChatterBotThought Think(ChatterBotThought thought)
        {
            ...
}
```

to this

```
namespace ChatterBotAPI
{
    public interface ChatterBotSession
    {
        ChatterBotThought Think(ChatterBotThought thought);
        string Think(string text);
    }

    internal class PandorabotsSession : ChatterBotSession
    {
        private readonly System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, string> vars;

        public PandorabotsSession(string botid)
        {
            vars = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>();
            vars["botid"] = botid;
            vars["custid"] = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public ChatterBotThought Think(ChatterBotThought thought)
        {
            ...
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem? what you are trying achieve?

Comment: @un-lucky I borrowed [someone else's library](https://github.com/pierredavidbelanger/chatter-bot-api) and want to use it in a project of mine. My project uses a program that runs C# scripts on the fly and doesn't handle `using` directives properly, so I need everything to be specified via fully-qualified names.

Comment: @minseong Remove all the `using` lines then go through each compile error and specify the correct namespaced path.

Comment: @Rob finding all the paths would take forever though? Loading up google, searching for the name etc.

Comment: Remove one "using" at a time and paste that deleted namespace before every compilation error, then move on to the next?  Visual Studio has a quick right-click option to fix by fully qualifying a name, I've never used mono so I have no clue what that has.

Answer (score 3):

- [Install Resharper Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/).
- Go to Resharper tab => Options...
- Go to Code Editing section => C# => Code Style
- Tick Prefer fully qualified references. (and save changes)
- Right click on your project and select CleanUp code. (Or press Ctrl E + Ctrl C)
- select Full Clean up and you are good to go (if you don't want full clean up then you can make your own profile and only chose Coding style to be applied.)

Comment: I'm not actually using Visual Studio, but I upvoted this because it is a good answer.

Comment: @minseong thanks. I know visual studio is heavy IDE but its really worth it. specially when mixed with resharper. try it some time  :)

Comment: Is there any benefits to use qualified names instead of using statements especially when using Linker?

Comment: @amir no-family If two library class names collide then you need partially or fully qualified name depending on namespaces. If namespace names also collide (with other namespace or types) then you may have to use fully qualified names.